# Python - shopping cart - problem with while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am aiming to amend the quantity of an item from my shopping cart by removing the quantity of a particular item. I am using a while loop to do this, however my while loop does not seem to be ending.

I want it to end so that code goes back to choosing the option (1. add an item 2. amend 3. delete item 4. view basket)

Any ideas on how to achieve this efficiently?

Would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks.

```
elif option == 2:
    item2 = input("Select the item you would like to amend: Parcel or Letter: ")
    item2_updated = item2.capitalize()

    while item2_updated != None:
        if item2_updated in shopping_basket:
            print ("Current item quantity: ")
            print(item2_updated,":",shopping_basket[item2_updated])
            quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity to remove: "))
            shopping_basket[item2_updated] = shopping_basket[item2_updated] - quantity
            print(item2_updated,":",shopping_basket[item2_updated])
        elif item2_updated != None:
            print("Item not in the cart")
    else:
        print("Item not in the cart")   

elif option == 3:
    item = input("Enter an item: ")
    del(shopping_basket[updated_item])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need

```py
elif item2_updated != None:
            print("Item not in the cart")
```

and avoid using `while... else` it's confusing.

Secondly, in your `while` loop you are not changing the value of `item2_updated` so `item2_updated` will never be `None`. It will always be the value the user initially sent in to `input()`.

What you want to do is put the `while` loop at the very top and use `if...elif...else` to update and change. Something like this:

```py
while True:
    if option == 1: 
        # do something
    elif option == 2:
        if item2_updated in shopping_basket:
            # do something (No while loop here)
    else:
        # do something else
```

You can also have a special option to "quit" which will `break` out of the `while` loop